# mirror modifier leaves a gap

Tags: modeling, mirror

[image: the gap]
[image: my settings]

My mirror modifier leaves a gap and I can't move the edges in to close it. What's the fix?

Comment: Remove the internal face (would be internal when mirror gap removed) then move the vertices until the gap is closed.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have subsurf on or something in the list before mirroring?
Sort of has that look.

Otherwise can, with clipping on for the mirror, drag verts to center.

Comment: Yes I did have a subsurb before mirror.

Comment: Make the mirror come before the subsurf. Infact make the mirror modifier top of the list

Answer (score 0):

You can increase merge limit. It's usually 0,000001 but here it should be more

**or**

set origin to one of the vertices and then mirror.

Before that remove all unnecessary verts/faces/edges as @rob says.